# How to fix encoding errors programmatically in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, dtd

I am trying to batch process thousands of XML files from the command line, but I am getting various error messages relating to invalid characters.

So far, I have been able to fix this in two different ways:

- Opening the offending file in Notepad and going to Save As > UTF-8
- Adding the encoding to the XML declaration (for some reason
  ISO-8859-1 also works)

I am puzzled as to why I am getting these error messages. I can see no mention of encoding in the original XML or the DTD, so the XML is not claiming to be something that it's not.

Given the number of files to be processed, I am also finding it labourious to fix each file individually. I was wondering if there is any way to fix this programmatically, for example in the XSLT stylesheet?

The error message is:

```
 Error on line 80 column 128 of 12345.dxl: SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Invalid byte 1 of 1-byte UTF-8 sequence.
```

Column 128 line 80 seems to correspond with a missing single curly quote: ("this governments Local Services Realignment exercise").

I tried adding a character map to the XSLT, but I still get the same error:

```
<xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="no" use-character-maps="curly_quotes"/>
<xsl:character-map name="curly_quotes">
    <xsl:output-character character="&#146;" string="‘"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#147;" string="’"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#148;" string="“"/>
    <xsl:output-character character="&#150;" string="”"/>
</xsl:character-map>
```

Comment: Adding an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful.

Comment: XML files without encoding default to UTF-8. To batch convert encodings, use a tool like iconv.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @nwellnhof ... I'll check out the tool you suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question as posed:  In general (but see below), one cannot fix encoding errors programmatically in XSLT, because XSLT acts upon the parsed XML document, and encoding errors typically prevent the document from being parsed correctly, which strictly speaking means there *is* no XML document present, only a stream of octets which fails to manage XML well-formedness.

As @nwellnhof points out, the tool to use is a character-set converter like iconv.

Note that while in the general case documents with encoding errors or inaccurate encoding declarations won't make it through the XML parsing phase, there can be exceptions:  not all errors in the encoding declaration are reliably detectable.  If, for example, one had a batch of documents all labeled as being in ISO 8859-1, although in fact they were in ISO 8859-15 (or, I think, pretty much any other part of ISO 8859), then it's unlikely that an XML parser could detect the error; an XSLT stylesheet that performs a near-identity transform and writes its input out with the desired encoding declaration could fix such an error.  But this is a very special case.  Further discussion (for those who enjoy this sort of question) may be found at http://cmsmcq.com/2007/dialog.surrogates.xml

Answer (score 0):

I installed the iconv tool and it does indeed fit the bill. I haven't yet figured out the syntax for batch processing, though. For that, I've posted a separate question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40681766/syntax-for-iconv-batch-conversions).